# How do I display the notification message in android what I get from the server

Tags: android

```
public class PushReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    {

        NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);

        mBuilder.setContentTitle("Notification Alert");
        mBuilder.setContentText("Medicine has not been taken");
        mBuilder.setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_info);
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);
        mBuilder.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

This is my code. How do I display the message what I get from the server and not what I type here?

Comment: whats your problem??

Comment: Follow this nice example : http://www.androidhive.info/2015/06/android-push-notifications-using-parse-com/

Answer (score 0):

All the data you sent from via push can be retrieved from the intent itself.

[check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871454/android-push-notification-get-data-store-and-display-on-new-activity-on-click)

Comment: try to explain the 'check here' link a little bit instead of simply redirecting him to a Web page. Thanks