# how to save notification to my android application and How retrieve data

Tags: android, android-studio, push-notification, android-notifications

i developed simple Notification application by using Firebase and i received notifications but unable to add those Notification to my android application

Comment: Can you please elaborate what is the exact question and problem, this is not understood from your description (Usually a question ends with - ?)
On the one hand you state that you want to save the notifications, But in the description you imply that you cannot add the notifications to somewhere, Please be clear!

Comment: Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21871454/android-push-notification-get-data-store-and-display-on-new-activity-on-click

Answer (score 0):

You can use SQL Lite DB to store this notifications and this data can be retrieved for future.

Comment: data you can retrieve from DB table where you have stored the data.

Comment: no i retrieve data from notifications  (server send notifications )

Comment: Store the same data in db

Comment: You are using FirebaseIntent Service to get or show notification? In that service call db class and insert the data into your databse