# How to show custom notification dialog when application is open in android using Onesignal

Tags: android, push-notification, android-dialog, onesignal

I have used Onesignal for push notifications in my android application. I am getting notifications properly. When the app is closed the notifications comes on notifications bar correctly. But I nee to show the received notifications with my custom dialog, when the application is opened. I have tried it . But I couldn't be achieve. Anybody can help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Use sharedPreference or SqLite to store last notification and show when app open next time.**

Here is example when and where you need to store notification message . You just need to get that message when user open app next time or when click on notification.

[Answer given by manoj](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22034010/6333971)